# XMLHttpRequest post files fails if the server doesn't read content but instead sends a response (even with code 200)

Tags: javascript, forms, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm using the following code to send files from a form to the server:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const formElement = document.getElementById('form');

request.upload.addEventListener("progress", (e) => {
    console.log("progress: " + e.loaded + "/" + e.total);
});
// request load handler (transfer complete)
request.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});

request.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});

// request error handler
request.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
        console.log(e, request)
});
request.open("post", formElement.action);
request.responseType = "json";
request.send(new FormData(formElement));
```

The server may respond before reading the contents of the files in some condition, and I want to get that response and handle it on the client side.

But it seems that I only get an error event triggered (response with status 0, an empty status text of type json), and 2 readystatechange events with readystate 1 and readystate 4 (same empty response). if the server simply return a response without reading the contents.

I also don't see any response when looking at the POST request in the browser's dev tool (F12->Network tab->Respons)

With curl (`curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "data=blabla" localhost:5000/upload`) I'm able to post and get the expected response, but not with XMLHttpRequest.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Kindly mention the complete error which you are getting so everyone can understand.

Comment: @kodesensei I've edited the question, I don't get an error, I get an error event with the XMLHttpRequest... And when looking in the F12 Network tab at the sent request, I see no response has been received for it. But my server logs having sent a response, and I do see this response using curl instead of XMLHttpRequest... (curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "data=blablavl" localhost:5000/upload)